# how set data source of a stimulsoft report to a gridview?

Tags: c#, gridview, linq-to-sql, report, stimulsoft

I want to design a report in stimulsoft where the data displayed is changed by filtering in gridview. How can I do this? I designed my report and changed the data source by code, but my report always shows all the data instead of filtered data.
I am using LINQ for manipulation data in a database and my environment is C3 windows application form.

Comment: Try setting the DataSource to null and then back to the report.  The refresh method for the gridview isn't recognizing the data changing.  Setting the DataSource to null will refresh the control.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But how can I set data source to null while I want to  design my report and and specify the location of fields on report?

Comment: I said to set to null and then back to original source.  Setting to null for one instruction shouldn't effect the design.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how you pass data to the report. If you use RegData method, you should call it again and Render the report with new data. Then just refresh the Viewer.